# Doble liberación de memoria en c

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy trabajando con un TAD en C en el cual tengo que ampliar algunas funciones, pero tengo un problema con la liberación de memoria, pues me da un error de doble liberación que no soy capaz de solucionar.

En el .h tengo esto:

```
typedef void * vectorT;
```

Y en el main inicializo el vector de la siguiente forma:

```
vectorT vec=NULL;
```

Tengo una función para crear el vector, pero antes de crearlo, en el main compruebo si no es nulo (por si ya ha sido creado antes) para liberarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
if(vec!=NULL){
        liberar(&vec);
    }
```

Y la función liberar:

```
void liberar(vectorT *vec){

free(vec);
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa e intento crear un vector, me salta el error de la doble liberación de memoria. También libero memoria al final del programa y sucede lo mismo.
¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La inicialización es correcta:

```
vectorT vec=NULL;
```

Pero esto es **erróneo**:

```
void liberar( vectorT *vec ){
  free( vec );
}
```

Esperas un puntero a un `typedef` que es, a su vez, otro puntero; es como si hicieras

```
void liberar( void **vec ) { ...
```

Por lo tanto, tu llamada a la función es igualmente **errónea**:

```
if( vec != NULL ) {
  liberar( &vec );
}
```

Puesto que estas pasando la dirección de un tipo, que, como dijimos, es a su vez un puntero.

La forma correcta sería:

```
void liberar( vectorT vec ) {
  free( vec );
}
```

y

```
if( vec != NULL ) {
  liberar( vec );
}
```

**EDIT**

Como acertadamente indica PaperBirdMaster en su comentario, después de liberar el bloque, lo correcto es volver a asignarle `NULL`:

```
if( vec != NULL ) {
  liberar( vec );
  vec = NULL;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo, ahora parece que funciona correctamente, ¡muchas gracias por la respuesta! @Dolmenes

Comment: @kalia, si la respuesta soluciona tu problema, considera *votarla* (flechita arriba, a la izquierda), y/o *aceptarla* (símbolo del *check*, a la izquierda, debajo de  la puntuación). Es el modo de agradecer el trabajo de los demás; échale un vistazo a [¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana (y se pierde)?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: A parte, después de liberar el puntero, debe ponerlo a `NULL`, de lo contrario en un siguiente pase de la función `free` usando `vec` como parámetro lo intentará liberar de nuevo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ¡¡ Despiste el mio !! Muy cierto, edito la respuesta.